# What's the difference between 貰えます (moraemasu) and いただけます (itadakemasu)? Which sounds more natural when talking about bags?

Tags: words

Example

> [1](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=51735&j=morae) "袋を貰えますか？ fukuro wo moraemasu ka?"
>
> [2](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=itadakemasu%20&e=&search=Search%20%3E) "袋をいただけますか？ fukuro o itadakemasu ka?"

Both mean "Can I have a bag?". However, what is the difference between itadakemasu and moraemasu?

moraemasu is [defined as to receive; to take; to accept](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=51735&j=morae)
itadakemasu [has a similar definition](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=itadakemasu%20&e=&search=Search%20%3E)

So what is the difference and what would be more natural?

Please refer to the examples in your answer.

Comment: Hint:  Make sure you're not confusing "can I" with "may I".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both natural. Which you should use depends on the situation.

**いただきます**　is 敬語{けいご} which means that you only use it in situations talking to someone who is clearly above you in social status or in situations where being polite is a must - such as talking with a customer.

**もらう**, on the other hand, is just neutral. You will hear もらう a lot more often unless you hang out with a "polite" crowd.

As far as how to decide when to use which, refer to [this write-up](http://www.yutaaoki.com/blog/when-to-use-keigo-honorific-speech-hierarchy-in-japanese-society) - it is pretty thorough. Just remember, if you are ever not sure, just stick to です and ます form and you should be okay. Just remember to ask someone later.

Comment: Is "being polite is not an option" a typo?

Comment: No, because there are situations where you can go either way depending on your personality, and there are most definitely people who speak polite more often than is necessary.

Comment: @naruto Maybe he means 'you don't get a choice in the matter'. It certainly reads to me like 'you must not be polite', but rereading it I think he means 'you have no option but to be polite', or 'being polite is not an *option*; it's a mandate.'

Comment: Edited for clarity. I didn't realize how misleading that was at first. Thank you for pointing it out.